# Python having issue parsing formate string date to date object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to parse the below `String` into `Date Object` but the result I am getting is wrong.

```
date = datetime.strptime(str_time, '%m/%w/%Y %H:%M:%S')
-> here date = 2016-01-01 00:09:55

formated_date_str = date.strftime('%m %H %A')
-> here formated_date_str = 01 00 Friday 

formated_date = datetime.strptime(formated_date_str, '%m %H %A')
-> here formated_date = 1900-01-01 00:00:00    

return (formated_date.month, formated_date.hour, formated_date.day)
```

As you can see `formated_date` value is wrong, I am expecting it to be `01 00 Friday`.

Comment: `str_time` is what?

Comment: `date` is a `Date Object` already... And `formatted_date_str` is already what you expected. What is all that extra stuff?

Comment: `date = datetime.strptime(str_time, '%m/%w/%Y %H:%M:%S')`

This is parsing your 'day' to be the weekday.  So not the actual date but Sun-Sat.  Are you meaning to do this?  Or are you meaning to pass in a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to parse the below String into Date Object

`datetime.strptime` is doing that for you.

> As you can see formated_date value is wrong

First, the output at step 3 is actually `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0)`

Which is not really wrong. You did `datetime.strptime('01 00 Friday', '%m %H %A')`, which contains no information about a year, minute, second... So, `year=1900,month=01,day=01,hour=01` makes sense

> I am expecting it to be 01 00 Friday

It already is

> ```
> -> here formated_date_str = 01 00 Friday
> ```

Comment: Hey, I just want convert '01 00 Friday' a date object from string. thats why I used strptime. How can I convert '01 00 Friday ' to date

Comment: That's what step 3 did.